# Función Javascript con valores de PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Realicé la siguiente función en php para consultar el valor de una tabla

```
function Consultar()

{
  global $g_idq;  

  $sql="select sw_genera_consulta from ventas_Saldos
    where sw_genera_consulta=1";
  p_query($sql);
  $registro=f_next_row($g_idq);
  $sw_genera_consulta=$registro['sw_genera_consulta'];

  return $sw_genera_consulta;
}
```

Deseo poder tomar el valor de esta consulta y realizar una funcion en javascript

esto es para que al momento de presionar el botón de generar, si este valor es 1, me frene la consulta y me genere una alerta.

no se como enviar este valor a una funcion de javascrips

lo intente de la siguiente forma, pero no obtengo ningun resultado.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    function generar_consulta(){

        var gen_consulta = '<?php echo $genera_reporte;?>'


      if(gen_consulta==1){

         Alert('Actualmente ya se encuentra ejecutando una consulta. Espere un momento e intentelo de nuevo');

        return false;
      }
      else{

        return true;
      } 

    }
</script>";
```

Comment: Creo que falta un poco mas de informacion, no indicas que valor contiene `$genera_reporte` ni donde usas la primera funcion  `Consultar()`?

Answer (score 3):

La mejor opción es utilizar AJAX. Esto es porque puedes utilizar mejor la ventaja de comunicar tu codigo cliente con tu codigo servidor y utilizar de mejor manera los datos. Tambien el codigo es mas limpio

Cuando hagas click en el boton generar, haces el llamado

```
$('#generar').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "consulta.php", 
        success: function(result){
           if (result.ejecucion == 1) {
               alert('Actualmente ya se encuentra ejecutando una consulta. Espere un momento e intentelo de nuevo');
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Y en tu archivo Consulta.php

```
$result = array('ejecucion' => 0);
//tu codigo....
$result[ejecucion] = $sw_genera_consulta
return $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

### Codigo

```
<?php
$genera_reporte = 1;    // Aqui viene la funcion que determina si se genera el reporte
?>
<html
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function generar_consulta(){
            var gen_consulta = '<?php echo $genera_reporte; ?>';
            if(gen_consulta == 1){
                alert('Actualmente ya se encuentra ejecutando una consulta. Espere un momento e intentelo de nuevo');
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Haz click" onclick="generar_consulta();">
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Explicacion

Aunque **no necesariamente es la mejor manera de solucionar tu problema**, podriamos entrar a explicar algunos terminos del uso de PHP en un mismo lugar con Javascript.

Primero, debes tener en cuenta, que no siempre es necesario hacer esto:

```
<?php
   echo "<input type='button' value='Boton'>";
?>
```

Ya que PHP se usa como una etiqueta en HTML, podrias en su lugar hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php
// Codigo PHP
?>
   <input type='button' value='Boton'>
<?php
// Mas codigo PHP
?>
```

Queda tu codigo mas entendible y en algunos IDE's incluso queda mas manejable el codigo, ya que se puede separar el PHP del HTML.

Para tu caso, he **separado el PHP del HTML**, de modo que la funcion `generar_consulta()` se escribe directamente en el `<head>` sin necesidad de imprimirse con PHP, y por ultimo solo hemos dejado esta variable con PHP embebido:

```
var gen_consulta = '<?php echo $genera_reporte; ?>';
```

De modo que **cuando se interprete el cuerpo de la pagina** se reemplazara `$genera_reporte` por el valor que esta contenga, siendo asi asignado a la variable `gen_consulta` de Javascript.

Puede usar [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/), para verificar el codigo de PHP en linea.

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo así:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    function generar_consulta(){

        var gen_consulta = '".$genera_reporte."';


      if(gen_consulta==1){

         Alert('Actualmente ya se encuentra ejecutando una consulta. Espere un momento e intentelo de nuevo');

        return false;
      }
      else{

        return true;
      } 

    }
</script>";
```

El problema es que 'echo' imprime texto plano, asi que '', se imprime como tal en la página. Lo que hacemos es concatenar '$genera_reporte' en el 'echo'.

Comment: Creo que no es la mejor manera de hacerlo, debería recomendar el uso de AJAX, para ejecutar el archivo PHP y obtener el valor de manera directa.

Comment: Claro que hay mejores maneras de hacerlo, pero me limité a responder la pregunta. De esta forma puede usar una variable de php con javascript.

Comment: Incluso sin contemplar AJAX como solución, hay mejores formas de hacerlo. No es necesario imprimir todo el script en una cadena, bastaba con el uso del operador `<?= $variable ?>` dentro del código javascript. Si mejoras eso, tienes mi **upvote**.